# HTTP Archive format for Servicestack Services

Tags: servicestack, har

Is there any quick way to automatically generate HAR for ServiceStack Services to be used for API Documentation tools like API Embed?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use existing tools?

With [Swagger API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API) your API will be automatically documented and testable.
If you prefer, you can use [ServiceStack Metadata](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Metadata-page) page too. It's less sexy than Swagger, but it's ok, it does the job.